# Python while loop data collection optimisation

Tags: python, list, sockets

I have a while loop designed to read data from a high frequency data acquisition module.

When I try take the samples at a higher frequency stride(being) lower, I get a socket error reset by peer on `data = self.vse.recv(datalen)`. I think too much data is being sent before it can be collected / not being collected fast enough.

Some optimisation has been done already, allowing me to increase the frequency. Is there any more optimisation that can be made to this?

```
datalen = 12+256*4
i = 0 
 
while time.time()- start < (self.sample_length):

            try:
                    data = self.vse.recv(datalen)
            except:
                    pass
            
            if len(data) ==datalen:
                    
                    overlap = i % stride
                    unpacked = struct.unpack('hhbbbbHH64f64f64f64f', data)
                    asda = list(unpacked)[8:]
                    data_list1.extend(asda[int(stride-(overlap)):64:stride])
                    data_list2.extend(asda[int(64+int(stride-overlap)):128:stride])
                    data_list3.extend(asda[int(128+int(stride-overlap)):192:stride])
                    data_list4.extend(asda[int(192+int(stride-overlap)):256:stride])
                                    
                    i += 64
```

The error I get back is:

```
data = self.vse.recv(datalen)

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] and the **entire** error output.

Comment: Remove the blanket `except: pass` you should at least print the execption because your current code hides all exceptions and who knows what's happening - not even you. How fast is the data arriving?